# WatchOS WidgetKit Image issue

Tags: swiftui, watchos, widgetkit

In watch os widgetkit, I need help to make my image override the actual colors of the watch to always show thew image in actual color.

If this is not feasible, need help in how to render the image to support accent behaviour like earth widget in astronomy. It adds a shade and some info is visible and for my image, it is showing as flat one color.

Didn't get much info from apple docs regarding this.

Adding image of earth widget in astronomy.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znTh9.png)

i tried using widgetAccentable modifier with both true and false but that is not override the color of watch. Even when i decide to accept it. the information of image is getting lost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can force an image to draw in full colour, but to use the accenting, you need to create an SF symbol with your image and annotate the appropriate layers for accenting. I believe Apple's WidgetKit documentation has information about this.

Comment: But that only allow to use the accent color and white color only not like the image that i have shared in my question

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I don't believe you can override the colour and force it to draw in a different colour. What I ended up doing was not using an SF symbol, but a regular SVG. Try changing the alpha channels on portions of your image and it should draw the accented colour there.