# Current time realtime in ios widget

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit

I know that there are answers that it is not possible to create text label in Widget that will show current time and will be updating in real-time, but how still some apps do so ?
They are showing seconds in widget.

Let me give few example of these apps live on app store.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/flip-clock-digital-widgets/id1181028777
- https://apps.apple.com/app/id1435058152

There are many many more.

Tried to create clock widget, but widget is updating only each minute only that too in simulator.

- Creation of timeline not helped
- "Keeping a Widget Up To Date" not working with current time, only timers, etc

Comment: Animations on WidgetKit were only possible via private API before iOS 17. iOS 17 introduces some new possibilities and it has restricted the old private api access. You can watch a couple WWDC videos from last month on the Developer App

Comment: @loremipsum Thank you for you reply. I checked Animations on WidgetKit and based on that landed on a article which solved my prob. For any others reference - https://www.tridhyatech.com/blog/make-animated-live-widgets-in-the-iphone-lock-screen-using-swiftui  Also if have any idea how to achieve this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76770368/watchos-widgetkit-image-issue